"FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host" for aws rds postgres
I have to ubuntu 22.04 vm machine. I want to access remote postgresql
Vm1: 10.64.105.106
Vm2:10.64.105.107

In VM1  configuration

apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib -y
sudo -u postgres psql
CREATE ROLE testdb WITH REPLICATION LOGIN PASSWORD 'password123';
\q

sudo vim /etc/postgresql/16/main/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'

sudo vim /etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf
host    all all 10.64.105.107/24    md5
sudo systemctl restart postgresql

In vm2 config
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib -y


What was the complete error message in the PostgreSQL server's log file?
